# Embedded WebDAV server

Tags: c#, http, sockets, embedded, webdav

I know this was probably asked before, but most things I found are half-finished. Is there a `C#` library that would enable me to embed a small (preferably high speed) `WebDAV` server and expand it to serve files from my backing store? Also, if no such thing exists, is there a similar `HTTP/S` server which is modular enough for `WebDAV` to be built on top of it?

Comment: I just wish a library that I could easily plug into existing sevice and iss is kinda overkill for that.

Comment: have you seen this? https://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist server components from [WebDavSystem](http://www.webdavsystem.com/) and there exist WebDAV server components in our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-webdav.php) products. Both are available for .NET. Ours can be used with any transport, not necessarily HTTP(S).

Comment: I'm looking for somethin in the lines of OSS,because at the end I plan to release my project to the public.